# System not booting up after keeping it idle for few hourse

Tags: boot, updates, 20.04, boot-repair, helpfile

I recently updated my system to ubuntu 20.04. A few days back I encountered a problem that whenever I turn on my device it does not turn on battery instead I need to take the battery out and plug in the charger and switch on the laptop. after that my laptop works fine. but after every interval of around 4 hours or more it juts does the same.

Is there anybody else who is facing this problem or any similar problem?

I think it is a problem with some new software updates which I had installed on my laptop.